# Escape field in LIKE query

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query:

```
SELECT `att`.`val` FROM `att` WHERE NOT (`att`.`val` LIKE `att`.`val`);
```

Should return nothing, right?

But it returns all the `val`s that have a backslash in them.

How do I make it return nothing?

`val` is a `varchar(1024)` field (not primary and not null).

This of course is a useless query but it is a simplified version of another query that doesn't work because of the same reason.

I'm using mysql 5.6.20.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I want to escape every character that needs escaping so the query will work as intended. Not just backslashes.

Comment: So you want the val field to always return null

Comment: Perhaps use `REPLACE(att.val, '\\', '')` ?

Comment: @Matt what do you mean?

Comment: @EllaShar you havent specified what field you want escaping?

Comment: @Coloco it works but hacky and can give wrong results (if removing the backslash will make the text equal to another text). Also maybe there are other characters that need escaping?

Comment: Yeah my SQL is always hacky for some reason, but you are right that in some rare cases it might give you weird results. Not sure if an ideal solution exists tho.

Comment: Can You replace `LIKE` with `=`?

Comment: No because in the real (not simplified) situation I don't compare a string to itself. This is just a simple testing example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the condition to:

```
WHERE NOT (`att`.`val` LIKE replace(`att`.`val`,'\\','\\\\'))
```

- this replaces single backslashes with double backslashes in `val`, so that instead of acting as escape characters, they are treated as literal backslashes by the `like` expression. (The first backslash escapes the second.)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a general way to escape all the characters that need escaping? Not just backslashes

Comment: @EllaShar: If there is, I'm afraid I don't know what it is.

Comment: By definition, only the escape character needs escaping :) However, you probably want to also escape characters `%` and `_` which have a special meaning in a `LIKE` clause (or just make a plain comparison).